# Ember Communication Between Components

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I'm developing a webapp to display and search documents. I've laid out the main wrapper div like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    {{searchComponent searchComponent=searchComponent}}
    {{pdfViewer pdfSearchComponent=searchComponent}}
</div>
```

This allows me to later add other types of viewers in there, like so:

```
{{otherViewer otherSearchComponent=searchComponent}}
```

The outer wrapper is an ember component as well. So it's controller looks like:

```
Ember.controller.extend({
   searchComponent: null,
   .
   .
   otherProperties,
   actions: { }
});
```

And the searching component binds itself on itialization, as inspired from this source: http://www.samselikoff.com/blog/getting-ember-components-to-respond-to-actions/

```
Ember.controller.extend({
    searchComponent: null,
    .
    .
    onStart: function(){
       this.searchComponent = this;
    }.on('init'),
    .
    .
    actions: {
        someAction: function() {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

So I can now reference the component from the main pdfViewer like this:

```
this.get('searchComponent').send('someAction')
```

To get the response, right now I bind another property to all the controllers / templates, and then watch for a change on that property in the viewer controller, after which I can place the results where they need to be.

Is there a way to send a 'message' from my 'pdfViewer' to my 'searchComponent' and receive a 'response' without explicitly binding them together, as above?

Comment: No, granted they are also tightly coupled in your implementation, and maybe one of them should be consuming the other instead of them being siblings. Or maybe the results from one of them should be bound as a property on the dependent component

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider using pub/sub through a `Service` event bus, in which your `searchComponent` and `pdfViewer` both emit and listen for messages, so can talk to each other. Sure, there is a dependency on the service, but from what I see your components are pretty application-specific anyway.

Something like:

```
_listen: function() {
  this.get('eventBus').on('message', this, 'handleMessage');
}.on('init'),

actions: {
  click() { this.get('eventBus').trigger('message', message); }
}
```

A few weeks ago I evaluated several approaches to parent-children component communication: http://emberigniter.com/parent-to-children-component-communication/, perhaps this helps somewhat.

Comment: I took a look at your post. It's an interesting read! Thanks for the solution!